# How to prove −AΔB=AΔC→C=−B?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Question is : There are `A`, `B`, `C` subset groups of universal set`U`. Prove that

$$ -A \Delta B = A\Delta C \to C = -B $$

As far as I see first part of expression is false as well as second, because for example $ -A \Delta B $ could not be equal to $A\Delta C$ also in second part `C` could not be equal to `-B`

But it is means that $ false \to fasle $ give us true.

I don't understand what is universal group `U` in this question thus I am not sure if my answer is right...

Comment: The first part isn't alwasy false, you should consider those cases that it's true.

Comment: F is undefined.   "subgroups groups of universal group" is confusion.  Do you mean subsets of a universal set?  A group is a set with a binary operator and some axioms.

Comment: @Manx but how I can consider that it is true if it is false...

Comment: @WilliamElliot you are right, edited my question

Comment: It is true e.g. if $A=\emptyset$ and $C=-B$. The universal set $U$ is hidden in the complements: $-X=U—X$.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko.  "Subsets of a universal set U" is what you intend.  Groups are not about set theory but about abstract alegbra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Set Identities we have:
\begin{align}
&\hspace{3ex}-A\bigtriangleup B=A\bigtriangleup C\\
&\equiv A^c\bigtriangleup B=A\bigtriangleup C\tag*{Set Complement Law}\\
&\equiv(A^c-B)\cup(B-A^c)=(A-C)\cup(C-A)\tag*{Symmetric difference}\\
&\equiv(A^c\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A)=(A\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap A^c)\tag*{Set Complement Law}\\
&\equiv(A^c\cap \color{orange}{B^c})\cup(A\cap \color{red}{B})=(A^c\cap \color{orange}{C})\cup(A\cap \color{red}{C^c})\tag*{Communative Law}\\
&\Rightarrow \color{orange}{C=B^c}\land \color{red}{C^c=B}\\
&\Rightarrow \color{orange}{C=-B}\tag*{Set Complement Law}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks, communative law was missing when I tried to solve it...